# SSL working with Self signed certificate but not with CA signed certificate

Tags: linux, ssl, certificate

I am trying to establish ssl connection between server(Linux) and client(POS terminal) using c language. I am able to connect to server using Self signed cert but not with CA signed certificate. Connection terminates with ssl handshake error. I am using same set of files on both sides. i have checked certificate validity and its usable.
I have used different type of protocols as well such as TLSv1_2_client_method etc but no luck.
Thank you.

client.c

```
SSL_load_error_strings();
SSL_library_init();
OPENSSL_add_all_algorithms_noconf();

sslContext = SSL_CTX_new(SSLv23_client_method());
if (sslContext == NULL ){
    ERR_print_errors_fp(stderr);
    return SSLERR;
}

SSL_CTX_set_options(sslContext, SSL_OP_ALL | SSL_OP_NO_SSLv2);
SSL_CTX_set_options(sslContext, SSL_OP_SINGLE_DH_USE);
SSL_CTX_set_cipher_list(sslContext, CIPHERS_LIMIT);//all ciphers used

iRet = SSL_CTX_load_verify_locations(sslContext, con->szCA, NULL);
SSL_CTX_set_verify(sslContext,SSL_VERIFY_PEER,NULL);
SSL_CTX_set_default_passwd_cb_userdata(sslContext, "1234");
SSL_CTX_use_certificate_file(sslContext, con->szCert, SSL_FILETYPE_PEM);
SSL_CTX_use_PrivateKey_file(sslContext, con->szKey,SSL_FILETYPE_PEM);
SSL_CTX_check_private_key(sslContext);

# define SSL_ERROR_WANT_READ             2
    # define SSL_ERROR_WANT_WRITE            3
    while ((r = SSL_do_handshake(con->sslHandle)) != 1 && OsTimerCheck(&timer) > 0) {
    int err = SSL_get_error(con->sslHandle, r);
    if (err == SSL_ERROR_WANT_WRITE) {
        events |= POLLOUT;
        events &= ~POLLIN;
        OsLog( LOG_ERROR, "return want write set events %d\n", events);
    }
    else if (err == SSL_ERROR_WANT_READ) {
        events |= EPOLLIN;
        events &= ~EPOLLOUT;
        OsLog( LOG_ERROR, "return want read set events %d\n", events);
    }
    else {
        OsLog( LOG_ERROR, "SSL_do_handshake return %d error %d errno %d 
    msg %s\n", r, err, errno, strerror(errno));
        ERR_print_errors_fp(stderr);
        check1(0, SSLERR_CONNECT, "do handshake error");
    }
```

LOGS:

return want write set events 12  \n
return want read set events 9  \n
SSL_do_handshake return -1 error 1 errno 0 msg Success \n
do handshake error \n

Server.c

```
SSL_library_init();
OpenSSL_add_all_algorithms();  /* load & register all cryptos, etc. */
SSL_load_error_strings();   /* load all error messages */
if ((ctx = SSL_CTX_new(SSLv23_server_method())) == NULL) 
if (SSL_CTX_use_certificate_file(ctx, CERT_FILE, SSL_FILETYPE_PEM)
if (SSL_CTX_use_PrivateKey_file(ctx, KEY_FILE, SSL_FILETYPE_PEM)
{
    fprintf(stderr, "ERROR: failed to load %s, please check the file.\n", KEY_FILE);
    slog_debug(0, "ERROR: failed to load %s, please check the file", KEY_FILE)
    return -1;
}
if ( SSL_CTX_check_private_key(ctx)!=SSL_SUCCESS )
if (!SSL_CTX_load_verify_locations (ctx, CA_FILE, NULL))
```

Comment: If the difference comes from the certificates and not the code you need to provide the certificates too. Also, what do you mean with *"same set of files"*. For server you need leaf certificate, chain and key, for client you need CA certificate. It is unclear how you use the files in your client since the code is incomplete. Also please show the detailed error description.

Comment: Hi @SteffenUllrich thanks for replying. I am using ca_bundle.crt, certificate.crt and private.key on both server and client. these three files are converted in .pem format using openssl. I am Using POS terminal as client.

Comment: client .c ->>  iRet = SSL_CTX_load_verify_locations(sslContext, con->szCA, NULL);
    SSL_CTX_set_verify(sslContext,SSL_VERIFY_PEER,NULL);
    SSL_CTX_set_default_passwd_cb_userdata(sslContext, "1234");
    SSL_CTX_use_certificate_file(sslContext, con->szCert, SSL_FILETYPE_PEM);
    SSL_CTX_use_PrivateKey_file(sslContext, con->szKey,SSL_FILETYPE_PEM);
    SSL_CTX_check_private_key(sslContext);

Comment: The client code does make sense to me: CA is set for verification but verification is switched off, certificate and key are set in client even though server does not request a client certificate.

Comment: This code is shared by device vendor and works for Self Signed certificate, as i am able to send data to server. and can you point out where verification is turned off?

Comment: `SSL_CTX_set_verify(sslContext,SSL_VERIFY_PEER,NULL);`

Comment: And the handshake error (still no details are given) might be due to a mismatch of the ciphers available (nothing known here) and the algorithms in the certificate (nothing known here either), i.e. like only RSA ciphers but a ECDSA certificate. Or it might be an unsupported signature algorithm ... too much unknown here, nothing to reproduce.

Comment: SSL_CTX_set_verify is set to VERIFY_PEER which i think means verification will be performed, if this is set to NONE then it does not give handshake error. Handshake error gives on SSL_accept API on server which returns 0 and SSL_do_handshake API returns -1 on Client. I am using same set of certificate on both sides so how could algorithm get mismatch.

Comment: @SteffenUllrich if you can share your email then i can share sample certificates with you. (due to security reasons)

Comment: *"SSL_CTX_set_verify is set to VERIFY_PEER "* - you are right, I was confused by the NULL (which is the optional callback). It is good to know that it succeeded if certificate validation was off - which means it is a problem of certificate validation and not of ciphers. My guess is that if it works with self-signed but not with CA issued that there are missing intermediate certificates: if the certificate hierarchy is *server - intermediate - root* and you only provide *server* in the server and trust *root* in the client then the trust chain cannot be build.

Comment: on both the sides same set of certificates are used

Comment: *"on both the sides same set of certificates are used"* -this is irrelevant and wrong in the first place. On the server side only the leaf certificate with key and intermediate are relevant. `SSL_CTX_load_verify_locations` on the server side is only relevant for validating client certificates, which are not requested On the client side only the root CA is relevant. `SSL_CTX_use_certificate_file` and `SSL_CTX_use_PrivateKey_file` are only relevant for client certificates which are not requested here.

Comment: Check that the *issuer* of `CERT_FILE` in the server is exactly the *subject* of `con->szCA` in the client. If not than you are likely missing intermediate certificates on the server side.

Comment: Ok but why same set of Self signed certificate works on both side with same code?

Comment: Because in a self-signed certificate no intermediate certificates are involved and thus they cannot be missing. Issuer and subject are the same with self-signed certificates.

Comment: I have stored serverca.pem, server.pem and serverkey.pem on SERVER and clientca.pem, client.pem and clientkey.pem are stored on CLIEnt side. is this right? if not then what should be the correct way?

Comment: There should be a server.pem and serverkey.pem on the server side - nothing else. There should be a ca.pem on the client side - nothing else. The issuer certificate for server.pem should be contained in ca.pem - which can be checked by comparing the issuer of server.pem against the subject of the certificate(s) in ca.pem. If there is no match certificate validation will fail since the trust chain cannot be build.

Comment: Hi @SteffenUllrich, I followed your instructions but still getting same error. I have added a SSL_do_handshake code snippet with logs for reference.

Comment: Error 1 is SSL_ERROR_SSL, i.e. you need to check the OpenSSL error queue. Use [ERR_get_error](https://www.openssl.org/docs/manmaster/man3/ERR_get_error.html) for this. But given that it works with verification disabled it is likely a verification error. Again, make sure that issuer of server.pem matches subject of ca.pem.

Comment: I verified server.pem using openssl verify command and it gave me error. but, when i appended data of serverca.pem into server.pem( i.e two certificates in server.pem(4.7Kb)) and now it does not give error. but when i compile my server code it throws error because of size. Certificate chain is RootCA->Intermediate Cert -> Leaf cert

Comment: If you are using an intermediate CA you have to add the intermediate-ca.pem to server.pem on the server site and use `SSL_CTX_use_certificate_chain_file` instead of `SSL_CTX_use_certificate_file` to load it. This way both leaf and intermediate get send to the client. *"...  but when i compile my server code it throws error because of size. ..."* - whenever you mention errors please provide full and exact error messages and how exactly it was caused (probably not due to compilation).

Comment: I have ca_bundle.crt(server_ca.pem), certificate.crt(server.pem) and private.key(serverkey.pem) files. and converted them to .PEM format 1) I used "SSL_CTX_use_certificate_file"  to load server.PEM and "SSL_CTX_use_PrivateKey_file" for serverkey.PEM on server. On client i used "SSL_CTX_load_verify_locations" to add server_ca.PEM. For reference, code and Errors added in Description as LOGS.

Comment: Second scenario: I concatinated server_ca.PEM and server.PEM and used "SSL_CTX_use_certificate_chain_file" API and "SSL_CTX_use_PrivateKey_file" for private.PEM on server. On client i used "SSL_CTX_load_verify_locations" to add server_ca.PEM. Maybe because of concatination of two certificates now key file is giving error as "failed to load Certs/serverkey.pem, please check the file" while make. If i remove concatination then it does not give make error. for reference, error sysntax is updated on description under server.c code

Comment: *"...failed to load Certs/serverkey.pem, please check the file ..."* - please use the error information OpenSSL provides, since they give more details. Also make sure that you add the certificates in the right order in server.pem, i.e. starting with leaf, followed by intermediate.

Comment: Order of certificates 1)leaf->ca then OpenSSL verify server.pem command gives error. 2)If ca-> leaf used then commands executes successfully

Comment: I have no idea what openssl verify command you are exactly using. And I'm kind of tired that I only get incomplete information - your own messages instead of more informative openssl error messages, just "openssl verify" instead of the exact command, ...

Comment: Sorry for the trouble. Following is the command “OpenSSL verify server.pem”. If leaf->CA cert followed then gives error as “error 20 at 0 depth lookup: unable to get local issuer certificate”. 2) CA->leaf followed them server.pem ok

Comment: `openssl verify` should be used with the leaf certificate as final argument, with root CA as `-CAfile` and with intermediates as `-untrusted`. Your are simply using it wrong which means that you cannot use the result as proof that everything is correct.

Comment: @SteffenUllrich, Certificates are used as per your suggestion. SSL_get_verify_result returns 1 i.e X509_V_ERR_UNSPECIFIED during Handshake. On client side in ca.pem file how many certificates should be there?

Comment: and SSL_get_peer_certificate API returns 5 i.e X509_V_ERR_UNABLE_TO_DECRYPT_CRL_SIGNATURE

Comment: I cannot really reproduce what you are doing since I only see incomplete snippets. In https://www.file.io/download/3eybJunvolOU you will find an archive with tests certificates and chain (root, middle, server+key)  which should reflect what you are currently using. Please use these for further experiments and provide the complete code of what you actually doing (use pastebin or similar). Only then I can reproduce what you are doing and continue to help you.

Comment: @SteffenUllrich Thank you for your extended support. Now ssl is working. Issue was with Certificate chain. GBU.